# React - Upload avatar to firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, file-upload, firebase-storage

Good afternoon, I can’t figure out how to upload a photo (avatar) to firebase, but so that the avatar for each user is different and saved at each user login. User registration via firebase Authentication

```
const [user, loading] = useAuthState(auth);
  const [image , setImage] = useState("");
  const storage = getStorage();

//upload function
  const upload = ()=>{
    const storageRef = ref(storage, `usersAvatar/${image.name}`);

    if(image == null) return;
    uploadBytes(storageRef, image).then(() =>{
      getDownloadURL(storageRef).then((url) => {
        setUrl(url);
      })
    })
  }


// return
<input type="file" onChange={(e)=>{setImage(e.target.files[0])}}/>
<button onClick={upload}>Upload</button>
```

Comment: Do you get any errors here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you use this location in Cloud Storage to store the user's image:

```
const storageRef = ref(storage, `usersAvatar/${image.name}`);
```

Any user who uploads the same `image.name` will end up overwriting anyone else's image.

What you'll want to do instead is based the upload location on the UID of the user. So for example:

```
const storageRef = ref(storage, `usersAvatar/${user.uid}/${image.name}`);
```